# Verifying the order/make up of URL, when you have the elements extracted from elsewhere

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, gherkin

I want to verify the order of a URL that is generated from faceted navigation on a development website.

EG *http://EcomWebsite.com/region/s/element1/element2/element3*

As part of a different test step I have extracted the strings I needed and I can test these are present in the url. I've been doing this as

```
assertThat(displayShopPage.getCurrentURL(),containsString(displayShopPage.element1()));
assertThat(displayShopPage.getCurrentURL(),containsString(displayShopPage.element2()));
assertThat(displayShopPage.getCurrentURL(),containsString(displayShopPage.element3()));
```

but I mention I need to check the order of the URL.

The step in question is

**"Then the order in which the values are included in the URL must be same order the values have within the facet"**

I'm still rather new and raw to Java, Selenium, and BDD so I thank you for any help you peeps can provide.

**EDIT:**
I'm trying to avoiding hard coded url's and what I want to check in the URL for several reasons.

Element1 etc come from class's that extract the text from faceted navigation element options.

So if I hard code the URL or the text from the element options if the product data changes and so the faceted navigation it will break the test.

Hence why I'm extracting the string from the elements to compare against the URL rather than just checking for the URL it self.

[image]

Comment: create a regex using elements of displayShopPage, after then you can compare

Comment: I don't know what a "regex" is, 'displayShopPage' is just a part of a URL being pulled from elsewhere in the frame work

Comment: it's regular expression, refer this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/regular-expressions-in-java/

Comment: its still not clear to me how to do it in this case im very new to scripting and automation. Can't I just use a differnt sytax or make up of the "containsString" part to include the all three of the "display.ShopPage.elements" as well as the URL "/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getCurrentURL() returns a string, right?  Why not simply compose the expected URL as a string then compare the strings?

```
currentUrl = displayShopPage.getCurrentURL()
expectedUrl = "http://EcomWebsite.com/" + displayShopPage.CF_PanelText() + "/s/" + displayShopPage.FacetGroup2OptionPanelText()   # compose this from your page source...it isn't clear above what the component order needs to be
assertEquals(currentUrl, expectedUrl)  # I made this up, I don't know the proper syntax for comparing strings
```

Comment: Hi there and thanks but I don't think this the kinda thing I'm avoiding. I'm trying to avoiding hard coded url's for several reasons.

Element1 etc come from class's that extract the text from faceted navigation element options.

So if I hard code the URL or the text from the element options if the product data changes and so the faceted navigation it will break the test. 

Hence why I'm extracting the string from the elements to compare against the URL rather than just checking for the URL it self.

Comment: sorry that I wasn't clear.  you already know how to extract the components of the expectedUrl from the page, so just construct it as a string.  It's not clear to me your required order, so I just made something up.  see the edit to my answer

Comment: btw, this is fairly rudimentary.  if you are adventurous, you could explore creating an instance of a java.net.URI.  I haven't written Java in a while, so I won't attempt to hack at that code for you.

Comment: haha maybe later, just want it to work in a robust way then later I can refactor, I have 10's 100's of BDD's to script for

Comment: I think I've solved it but your edit sent me in the right direction

        assertThat(displayShopPage.getCurrentURL(), containsString(displayShopPage.CF_PanelText() + "/" + displayShopPage.FacetGroup2Option1PanelText() + "/" + displayShopPage.FacetGroup3Option1PanelText()));

I've tested this with the wrong order and it fails correctly as well